# "command not found" in zsh after adding a command into /usr/local/bin

Tags: path, zsh

```
 ~ ll /usr/local/bin| grep vrl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31K 9月  29 09:38 vrlsubmit
➜  ~ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
➜  ~ vrlsubmit
zsh: command not found: vrlsubmit
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally somebody helped me:
Root cause is:

> I am trying to exec a 32bit command in 64bit system

Debug:

```
> file submit  # < submit stands for the command >

submit: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped

> ls /lib | grep ld
compat-ld
gold-ld
```

- Based on above "file submit", it tells "interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2" needed. But there are no /lib/ld-linux.so.2 file at all!!!

Solution:

> sudo apt-get install lib32z1 -y
> submit

```
Error: Missing one or more required arguments.

submit
```

Finished to resolve this issue!